# JS restore default/global functions

Tags: javascript, function, default, global, restore

This is a hypothetical question, it really doesn't have a practical use, but...

Let's say you were to do:

```
document.open = null;
```

How would one restore document.open to its original functionality, is this possible (without user-made temporary storage)? Is document.open stored in another location under a less known name? Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 10):

Overwriting `document.open` creates a variable/function named `open` directly on the `document` object. However, the original function was not on the object itself but its prototype - so you can indeed restore it.

The `open` function is from `HTMLDocument.prototype` so you can access it using `HTMLDocument.prototype.open`.

To call it directly, use `.call()` to specify the object to use it on:

```
HTMLDocument.prototype.open.call(document, ...);
```

You can also restore `document.open` it by simply assigning it:

```
document.open = HTMLDocument.prototype.open;
```

However, remember that `HTMLDocument` and thus `document` are host objects and it's usually a good idea not to mess with them - especially in IE things are likely to go haywire if you do so.

Comment: Ahah! Great to know, thankyou! :)

In response to your edits... Fascinating! I never knew this,thank you once again for the information! :) I will accept this as soon as I am able to

Comment: how would one go about doing that for something like `alert`? i.e. overriding `window.alert` with a custom function is fairly trivial, but the rollback is challenging without keeping a temp reference: http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/kcLBd/

Comment: `alert` is most likely defined directly on the `window` object and thus cannot be reached via other means. Since `alert` is not standardized you also cannot expect a solution that works in browser x to work in browser y.

Comment: This wont work in IE7/IE8, it has no HTMLDocument nor Window types.
How can I get to the original method in IE7/8 ?

Comment: The most likely answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 5):

```
delete document.open;
```

It's not intuitive, but using the delete keyword on a customized function will restore the original function, at least as long as the prototype hasn't been overwritten.

Example:

```
> console.log
function log() { [native code] }

> console.log = function() { }
function () { }

> console.log("Hello world");
undefined

> delete console.log;
true

> console.log("Hello world");
Hello world
```

Works the same way with document.open and other built-in functions.

Comment: `delete alert` and `delete window.alert` both fail, just as `window.alert = window.prototype.alert` fails in http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/kcLBd. Other than that, great answer.

Comment: Times have changed and it doesn't work anymore. Neither in Firefox nor Chromium-based. Tested with the exact same example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = document.open;
document.open = null;
```

and then you restore the original function with

```
document.open = temp;
```

Comment: Interesting -- Let's say you don't have the temp! Is there another way?

Comment: you need to create a reference in some way... e.g. run an immediate self executing anonymous function passing document.open as argument

Comment: I was mostly wondering if the browser stores a second reference on its own